# Close Quarters Realistic FPS

Tags: windows, game, windows-7

Over the years I've become a fan of realistic FPS/MilSim games such as ArmA II, ArmA III and the like. The problem is, most of the games I play take place on massive, sprawling maps that aren't very good for CQC combat. The AI is programmed to fight at this range and, most times, will begin shooting at you the second you begin shooting at it.

Lately I've been wanting a tactical/realistic FPS/MilSim game set in a CQC environment. Essentially my criteria are

- Close quarters combat (no enemies at 500 meters firing on me with mortars and a tank)
- Realistic (People should go down in a couple shots, guns should be loud, have weight, etc.)
- Coop (vs. the AI) and Multiplayer (vs. other players) options
- Reasonable critic/metacritic or player reception
- Must run on Windows 7, came out in the last 6-8 years with online multiplayer and still reasonably sized playerbase.

Other criteria that would be nice, but might narrow the scope too much:

- Is on Steam
- Medical system (bandages, med kits, morphine, etc.)
- Avid modding community
- 3D scopes
- 3D VOIP or 3D VOIP mod

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since we bombed miserably with TAKEDOWN, I thought we could redeem ourselves with... [Insurgency](http://store.steampowered.com/app/222880/?snr=1_7_7_151_150_1)!

- Firstly, it has a pretty good Metascore; [76/100 by critics and 8.9 by users.](http://www.metacritic.com/game/pc/insurgency) After playing it for a couple hours tonight, I would give it around 8.5/10. The only let downs I've found are that the control feel clunky sometimes and all footsteps seem sound the same.
- The realism is good, you'll die in a couple hits to the body and recoil management is definitely required when firing on a target.
- The maps are very similar to small Battlefield 3 maps and are well structured. There are also no vehicles, or long range explosives. The tutorial did mention an RPG, but I have yet to see one.
- You can play with bots, with other players, or even with bots and other players.
- Released last month on Steam, no problems running on Windows 7. Runs great on Windows 8.1.

All in all, it's a good game and I think I'll enjoy it for a long time. At $14.99 currently, it's fantastic value for the price.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't come across anything that matches the complexity that is ArmA in a CQC shooter, but [TAKEDOWN: Red Sabre](http://takedownthegame.com) seems like it might fit your first lot of criteria to a degree. It was released and marketed as a thinking-man's shooter, and an answer for all the hardcore tactical FPS fans out there.

It was however received very poorly by the FPS community as largely unfinished and broken. With time it may redeem it's current shortfalls. Beyond that, you may find it a suitable option in time.

Comment: Did you play it? What are your experiences? Please review this meta and adjust your answer: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality

Comment: I have not played it, but I did look into it quite a bit before deciding that it wasn't going to be for me. It is also the only publicised Tactical Hardcore Shooter I have found in my search for a better FPS.

Comment: As it stands the game boasts an impressively low [34 on Metacritic](http://www.metacritic.com/game/pc/takedown-red-sabre) and an even lower 2.6 user score. I've examined Takedown: Red Sabre before and would avoid it like the plague for this very reason.

Comment: I'm well aware of the poor ratings. It's interesting that you didn't mention taking a look at this game in your question though. Would have been helpful and saved me a downvote. :)

Comment: @MichaelFrank Sorry, I'm not the one that downvoted it if that helps at all. I hadn't even thought to mention Takedown: Red Sabre as the ratings fiasco had driven it out of my thoughts entirely. It is still a valid answer, just a bad game.